# Simplifying a Logarithmic Expression

Tags: logarithms

This is a really, very simple question, but I've never been an extremely confident mathematician and I just want to make sure that my attempt was correct. Oh and **this is homework** incase you were thinking I'm trying to sneak answers. :)  All logarithms are to base *b* . The original expression is:
$$
\log(4) - 3\log(1/3) + \log(2)
$$

So I decided, the first thing to do was to invoke the power law so they're all in the same form:

$$
\log(4) - \log(1/3^3) + \log(2) = \log(4) - \log(1/27) + \log(2)
$$

Then I used the subtraction law:

$$
\log(4 \cdot 27) + \log(2) = \log(108) + \log(2)
$$

And finally I applied the addition law:

$$
\log(108 \cdot2) = \log(216)
$$

The question was to simplify it to a single logarithm. I just wanted to ensure I had done this right. All the other answers in the paper evaluate to like $log(5)$ and 216 seemed a little out of place :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you've done that correctly.  I like to pull the negative sign up with the exponent to turn everything into addition, but what you've done is fine:

$$\log(4) - 3\log(1/3) + \log(2) = \log(4) + \log((1/3)^{-3}) + \log(2)$$

Answer (score 1):

Nicely done. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: So it's correct then?

Comment: Yep! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ah excellent! I've been programming for years, and I've gotten good at that. I've just got gaping holes in my math knowledge. Thanks for that :)